# writing a database-centric function with test-first

Tags: unit-testing

I'm trying to think about the best method to write a function whose primary operation is going to be doing crud on the database.  Here's what the overall structure of the function (sans any refactoring) will look like:

```
    public function cancelWorkRelease (workReleaseID number, key string){
        validate key...
        validate workrelease eligibility...
        perform cancellation tasks... /* database CRUD piece */
        return success or failure xml...
    }
```

Now each of the above lines will probably be split into its own function, and probably sub-functions, etc. I'm basically wondering what the best way to verify that the "perform cancellation tasks" function gets called when I write test 1.  Maybe I'm thinking too abstractly and can just ignore that piece in unit testing (I'm going to use method injection on the "perform cancellation tasks" function as I test so it won't actually run).  Am I overthinking this too much?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your program talks to the database through an API. Mock that API. Then you'll know if the function is saying the correct things through the API.  And you won't have to wait for the slow DB.

The API might be particular to that database but it's much nicer if it really is simple crud operations. That's easier to mock and means you aren't tied to a particular flavor of DB.